# Не работают Zabbix-оповещения через внешний скрипт (SMTP с авторизацией)

Tags: zabbix, smtp

Стоит Zabbix 2.2 на Debian. Создал скрипт отправки почты по SMTP с авторизацией в /usr/lib/zabbix/alertscripts/sendEmail.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
export smtpemailfrom=zbx@domain.ru
export zabbixemailto=$1
export zabbixsubject=$2
export zabbixbody=$3
export smtpserver=mail.domain.ru
export smtplogin=zbx
export smtppass=zbxPassword
/usr/bin/sendEmail -f $smtpemailfrom -t $zabbixemailto -u $zabbixsubject -m $zabbixbody -s $smtpserver:25 -xu $smtplogin -xp $smtppass
```

Права на sendEmail.sh 755. Если выполнить в консоли и передать соответствующие параметры, то письма приходят нормально.
Заббикс настроил по инструкции https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/ru/2.2/manual/config/notifications/media/script но при срабатывании триггера письма не приходят, хотя в Аудит->Действия пишет что письмо отправлено и никаких ошибок нет. А фактически письмо не приходит на почту. 
Пробовал сделать отправку почты на скрытый email сервиса sms.ru на те же события - всё хорошо отправлялось и работало.
Куда копать?

Answer (score 1):

Решено: http://toster.ru/q/112779?utm_source=email_toster&utm_medium=email_notification&utm_content=answer&utm_campaign=notifications

Comment: @cbone, По возможности, публикуйте решения на форуме, информацию по ссылке могут удалить.